# How do we show mathematically that the lump sum principle does not apply to perfect complements?

Tags: utility, perfect-complements

I want to show mathematically that the lump sum principle does not apply to perfect complements. I was able to show it applied with a specific Cobb-Douglas utility function, but I am not sure how to show it does *not* apply with a perfect complements utility function:
$$ U(x,y)=Min\{ax,by\} $$
or the form I am not sure about:
$$ U(x,y)= \lim_{\delta\to-\infty} [ ax^\delta + by^\delta]^{(1/\delta)}
$$
Any hints or corrections?
Thanks

Comment: The $\min$ form is fine. But this seems very straightforward; what process did you follow with Cobb-Douglas that does not work with perfect complements?

Comment: You can't use differentiation with a $\min$-function. Instead, draw the indifference curves and the different budget lines. It should then be easy to see why the principle doesn't apply. Finally, translate the argument into maths.

Comment: @Giskard This was not a generalized proof. I just found the utility difference for a specific example. See my attempt at a generalized proof for perfect substitutes here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4268077/how-do-we-show-mathematically-that-the-economic-lump-sum-principle-applies-to-pe